# 15T Freewheel Which Works on Flip Flop Hub

Tags: hub, freewheel, compatibility

I am building a Single Speed Freewheel and I read somewhere that manufactures don't make 15T freewheels that fit on a Flip Flop hub; only 16t and bigger. However, I would like a gain ratio above 3 and I already purchased a 48T chain ring.

Is it true that you can't buy 15T Freewheel that will work on a regular non BMX wheel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The normal freewheel thread is too large for cogs smaller than 16T. One source for the information is [Sheldon Brown's singlespeed page](http://www.sheldonbrown.com/singlespeed.html). It is a good one to read before buying any more parts.

A BMX flip flop hub will, however, take smaller freewheels that have smaller thread. Fixed/free flip flop hubs have the larger freewheel thread and similar sized thread with lock ring thread on the other side, these do not work with small freewheels.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Idk who downvoted you but this answered my question.

Comment: I downvoted because any answer to this question that doesn't mention the existent 15t freewheels for standard freewheel hubs is clearly incomplete.

Comment: @NathanKnutson you know, there is also an option to comment.

Answer (score 2):

It's probably not true, technically. AC Racing made a 15t freewheel that fits on a standard freewheel hub by placing the pawls outboard of the cog. It was widely regarded as poor quality and is no longer in production. But you could probably buy one somewhere out there if you wanted.

[image]